Why am I having Avoid using "px" as units; use "dp" instead in Android studio
Avoid using "px" as units; use "dp" instead
`<TextView
android:id="@+id/welcome_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Welcome!"
android:textSize="150px"
android:textColor="@color/material_dynamic_primary50"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="80px"
/>`

I tried using px instead of dp in android studio Java and it says Avoid using "px" as units; use "dp" instead

For text,  you really should use sp (scaled pixels). But, as the documentation covers, px is hardware pixels, and those can vary tremendously in size.

Ok...Thank you. I will change it to 'sp' and also read from the documentation.

@CommonsWare or Sur Nmai, one of you should probably make CommonsWare's comment an actual answer so you can mark this question as answered instead of leaving it open.
